# Extract a number from a txt file

Tags: python

Apologies to all, I am rewriting the question to be clearer than before.
I have text files that are renamed like this: 1.txt, 2.txt, ... etc. (for a total of 195 files).
These text files contain two blocks made like this:

Comment: what code have you written so far?

Comment: What does this have with machine learning to do? It seems like a trivial text parsing problem.

Comment: Open file, read lines, remember the previous line, check for the field you want to extract around, when you find it take the last token from the previous line and the next token after the match. `with open(file, "r") as lines: for line in lines: if line.startswith(" Alpha virt. eigenvalues --"): print(prev.split()[-1], line.split()[4]); prev=line`

Comment: What do you imagine are the necessary steps to solve the problem? (What steps would you take to solve the problem yourself, with pencil and paper?) What do and don't you know how to do? For example, do you know how to open a file and read lines from it? If you have a string that contains a line from the file, do you know how to check whether it contains `Alpha virt. eigenvalues --`? If you know how to do these things, then **why** (in your own words) do you get stuck when trying to write the code?

Comment: "It would be convenient if there was a way to open one text file at a time, extract the number" What do you mean by "the number"?

Comment: dear all, thank you for your answers. I have updated the question hoping it is clearer

Comment: Could you clarify the question a little more?  Add comments to the code for what you're trying to do at various points (at least one comment for the `for`, `with`, and `for` loops).  Are HUMO and LUMO acronyms?  Without context of their meaning, they aren't much more descriptive than a simple placeholder variable like `a`.   Last but not least - **Welcome to StackOverflow!**

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is stored in text.txt file. I only take the last 5 elements of a line.

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
    file_list = f.readlines()
new_list = [] 
for sentence in file_list:
    new_list.append(sentence.replace('\n', ''))
list_number = []
for element in new_list:
    list_number.append(element.split()[:-6:-1])
```

Output:

```
[['-0.34011', '-0.34412', '-0.34682', '-0.35095', '-0.35790'],
 ['-0.28924', '-0.30201', '-0.31434', '-0.32013', '-0.33775'],
 ['-0.27505', '-0.27672', '-0.28216', '-0.28518', '-0.28686'],
 ['0.02156', '0.00150', '-0.02072', '-0.10541', '-0.12386'],
 ['0.05155', '0.04675', '0.04449', '0.03997', '0.03129'],
 ['0.08236', '0.08193', '0.07459', '0.06358', '0.06062']]
```